# Bluebird promise: why it doesn't timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

So, I'm trying to model some long computation. for this purpose I'm computing the fibonacci number. In case when computation takes to much time I need to reject it.

**The question:** why `TimeoutErrror` handler doesn't work? How to fix the code?

```
const expect = require('chai').expect
const Promise = require('bluebird')

function profib(n, prev = '0', cur = '1') {
    return new Promise.resolve(n < 2)
      .then(function(isTerm) {
        if(isTerm) {
          return cur
        } else {
          n = n - 2
          return profib(n, cur, strAdd(cur, prev));
        }
      })
  }

const TIMEOUT = 10000
const N = 20000

describe('recursion', function() {
  it.only('cancelation', function() {
    this.timeout(2 * TIMEOUT)
    let prom = profib(N).timeout(1000)
      .catch(Promise.TimeoutError, function(e) {
        console.log('timeout', e)
        return '-1'
      })

    return prom.then((num) => {
      expect(num).equal('-1')
    })
  })
})

const strAdd = function(lnum, rnum) {
  lnum = lnum.split('').reverse();
  rnum = rnum.split('').reverse();
  var len = Math.max(lnum.length, rnum.length),
      acc = 0;
      res = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var subres = Number(lnum[i] || 0) + Number(rnum[i] || 0) + acc;
    acc = ~~(subres / 10); // integer division
    res.push(subres % 10);
  }
  if (acc !== 0) {
    res.push(acc);
  }
  return res.reverse().join('');
};
```

Some info about environment:

```
➜  node -v
v6.3.1
➜  npm list --depth=0
├── bluebird@3.4.6
├── chai@3.5.0
└── mocha@3.2.0
```

Comment: Are you using Mocha?, what test runner are you using?

Comment: added info about environment

Comment: The only way you can handle that kind of thing with JavaScript would be to cut your processing into small steps, and let other code than your loop run in-between those steps. An efficient way to do that would involve recursively-thenned Promises. Preferably in a WebWorker so you don't slow down the UI process.

Comment: (unless you know your timeout in advance, then your loop can check the time and break itself)

Comment: @Touffy the process is already cutted. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your code correctly `profib` does not exit until it's finished.

Timeouts are not interrupts. They are just events added to the list of events for the browser/node to run. The browser/node runs the next event when the code for the current event finishes.

Example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("timeout");
}, 1);

for(var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Even though the timeout is set for 1 millisecond it doesn't appear until after the loop finishes (Which takes about 5 seconds on my machine)

You can see the same problem with a simple forever loop

```
const TIMEOUT = 10000

describe('forever', function() {
  it.only('cancelation', function() {
    this.timeout(2 * TIMEOUT)

    while(true) { }   // loop forever
  })
})
```

Run in with your environment and you'll see it never times out. JavaScript does not support interrupts, it only supports events.

As for fixing the code you need to insert a call to setTimeout. For example, let's change forever loop so it exits (and therefore allows other events)

```
const TIMEOUT = 100

function alongtime(n) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    function loopTillDone() {
      if (n) {
        --n;
        setTimeout(loopTillDone);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    }
    loopTillDone();
  });
}


describe('forever', function() {
  it.only('cancelation', function(done) {
    this.timeout(2 * TIMEOUT)

    alongtime(100000000).then(done);
  })
})
```

Unfortunately using setTimeout is really a slow operation and arguably shouldn't be used in a function like `profib`. I don't really know what to suggest.

Comment: Yes, I did. I get the same issue as the forever loop above because your code is basically going to run to completion period. Unless your function `profib` exits while it's computing there is no way for a timeout to trigger. So you'll get your answer, the code will assume there's was no timeout (timeouts only trigger if an event can be processed). Hence you won't get your timeout error.

Comment: timeouts, in general or for promises, really only work for async stuff. You make a network request, your code exits, other events are processes, if you don't get the response event before the timeout event then you get your timeout. But if you're spinning inside a function and never exiting there's no way for the timeout to happen.

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstand you. And I asked a wrong question. Your answer is a correct reason why it works like this. Can you explain how to fix the code?

Comment: To fix the issue with setTimeout you can call it on every 100th iteration. It will help

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears because promises work in a "greedy" manner(it's my own explanation). For this reason function profib doesn't release event loop. To fix this issue I need to release event loop. The easiest way to do that with Promise.delay():

```
function profib(n, prev = '0', cur = '1') {
    return new Promise.resolve(n < 2)
      .then(function(isTerm) {
        if(isTerm) {
          return cur
        } else {
          n = n - 2
          return Promise.delay(0).then(() => profib(n, cur, strAdd(cur, prev));
        }
      })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

gman has already explained why your idea doesn't work. The simple and efficient solution would be to add a condition in your loop that checks the time and breaks, like thus :

```
var deadline = Date.now() + TIMEOUT

function profib(n, prev = '0', cur = '1') {
    if (Date.now() >= deadline) throw new Error("timed out")
    // your regular fib recursion here
}
```

Calling `profib` will either eventually return the result, or throw an error. However, it will block any other JavaScript from running while doing the calculation. Asynchronous execution isn't the solution here. Or at least, not all of it. What you need for such CPU-intensive tasks is a WebWorker to run it in another JavaScript context. Then you can wrap your WebWorker's communication channel in a Promise to get the API you envisioned originally.

Comment: Throwing an error isn't a good practice in the case. I want to cancel calculation and do a timeout on a caller site. And I can do that: check my answer